# Changing the string to camelcase in java with both underscores and digits

Tags: java, regex

I have found answers regarding changing underscore to camelcase But how to change the letters followed by underscore as well as digit to uppercase. The answers given in other question doesnot changes the letter followed by digit to uppercase.

I want both underscore as well as digit.

```
isbarrier1breached => isbarrier1Breached
barrier1_level => barrier1Level
```

i am using java as my programming language.

Answer (score 2):

This requirement seems to have just two rules:

- if a character is an underscore, don't output it
- if the previous character is an underscore or a digit, uppercase the current character

There are many potential algorithms, but one is to maintain a flag indicating whether whether we are in upper casing mode.

In pseudo code:

```
 doUppercase = false
 for each input char 'c' {
     # print char the appropriate way:
     if(c is not an underscore) {
        if(doUppercase) {
            append upper cased c to output
        } else {
            append lower cased c to output
        }
     }
     # set flag for next char
     doUppercase = (c is a number or c is an underscore)
  }
```

Another option is instead of storing a flag for the next iteration, store the actual previous character.

---

Or in Java:

```
  public String camelCase(String s) {
     StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
     boolean doUppercase = false;
     for(int i = 0; i<s.length();i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        // append if appropriate
        if(c != '_') {
           out.append(doUppercase ? Character.toUpperCase(c) : c);
        }
        // set capitalisation for next iteration
        doUppercase = ( c == '_' || Character.isDigit(c));
     }
     return out.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not too good, but it works.. :). Efficiency O(n)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1 = "abc2asda12asa";
        String s2 = "another_var_so_";
        if (s2.endsWith("_")) {
            s2 = s2.replaceAll("_$", "");
        }
        System.out.println(s2);
        while (s2.contains("_")) {
            int index = s2.indexOf("_");

            String s = s2.substring(index, index + 2);
            s2 = s2.replace(s, s.substring(1, s.length()).toUpperCase());

        }
        System.out.println(s2);
    if(!s1.substring(s1.length()-1, s1.length()).matches("\\d+$"))
    {


        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length() - j; i++) {
            if (s1.substring(i, i + 1).matches("\\d+")) {
                String s = s1.substring(i + 1, i + 2).toUpperCase();
                s1 = s1.replace(s1.substring(i, i + 2), s);
                j++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
    }
```

Comment: The code works fine... but have a little change in this line:     s1 = s1.replace(s1.substring(i+1, i + 2), s); // This will incorporate digit rather then removing it. Thanx for the answer

Comment: *Way* overcomplicated. Breaks if there are repeated patterns in the input. That is, "abc1def" -> "abc1Def", but "abc1abc" -> "Abc1Def". I'm not 100% sure it's O(1) either, because of the substring() in a loop.

Comment: ... and throws a StingIndexOutOfBoundsException for input "abc1".

Comment: @slim - Modified the code to check if last char is a number.. if yes, then do nothing :). thanks for looking into the code.